# Swift storing an Integer and displaying the changed Integer when reopening the app

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults

I have an app where when I click a button it increases the value of an Int. When I close the app and then open it again, I want the value of the Int to be whatever it was before closing it. This is in Swiftui and I have multiple Int values that I want to store and reload after closing and opening the app. I dont want where the user clicks a save button to save the Int value, but rather it saves automatically.

I tried AppStorage, but this slowed down the app way too much.

Comment: How did AppStorage “slow the app”? It’s absolutely the correct solution for this, but it sounds like you have other issues. Can you share your View’s code?

Comment: Please post your code and provide a Minimum Reproducable example -  this is **essential** for other developers to test your code and be able to help you.`

Comment: Please provide some more details including the code. Then we should able to test and find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too much data you can use UserDefaults.

Comment: AppStorage uses UserDefaults behind the scenes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).